# What is the easiest way to get rid of "else if... else if... else if..." statements?

Tags: c#, if-statement, optimization

I have code that generates a binary number associated with a wall according to certain rules, and I need to determine which type of wall is being used, knowing the binary number. As in example:

```
public static readonly HashSet<byte> WallDiagonalCornerUpRight = new()
{
    0b00000100,
    0b00000101
};
```

I call the private method, which returns the name of the desired tile. Everything works correctly and is even fast. But I just don't like the way it looks.

```
internal void SetSingleCornerWall(Vector2Int position, string binaryType)
{
    var typeAsByte = Convert.ToByte(binaryType, 2);
    TileBase tile = TileBase(typeAsByte, null);
    if (tile != null)
        SetSingleTile(wallTilemap, tile, position);
}

// I want to optimize this method
private TileBase TileBase(byte typeAsByte, TileBase tile)
{
    if (WallHashType.WallInnerCornerDownLeft.Contains(typeAsByte))
        tile = wallInnerCornerDownLeft;
    else if (WallHashType.WallInnerCornerDownRight.Contains(typeAsByte))
        tile = wallInnerCornerDownRight;
    else if (WallHashType.WallDiagonalCornerDownLeft.Contains(typeAsByte))
        tile = wallDiagonalCornerDownLeft;
    else if (WallHashType.WallDiagonalCornerDownRight.Contains(typeAsByte))
        tile = wallDiagonalCornerDownRight;
    else if (WallHashType.WallDiagonalCornerUpRight.Contains(typeAsByte))
        tile = wallDiagonalCornerUpRight;
    else if (WallHashType.WallDiagonalCornerUpLeft.Contains(typeAsByte))
        tile = wallDiagonalCornerUpLeft;
    else if (WallHashType.WallFullEightDirections.Contains(typeAsByte))
        tile = wallFull;
    else if (WallHashType.WallBottomEightDirections.Contains(typeAsByte))
        tile = wallBottom;
    return tile;
}
```

I assume a number of possible methods of code optimization, but I **can't** formulate any of them for me exactly.

What is the best way to improve the code in this situation?

Comment: Iterate these elements in a for loop.

Comment: Create a dictionary for the mapping and iterate it.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb your for loop is not going to work in this case because the tests are done across different WallHashType record fields which are not enumerated. For the same reason, a dictionary can't be used, it only removes the "Contains". Reflection on WallHashType fields could be used, but is very expensive in terms of performance. To be honest I think the above testing looks awful, it is not suitable for switch() case either, but it is probably the quickest way.. if it works and your records structure requires to store your "room" or "cube" geometries like this, keep it.

Comment: `WallHashType.WallInnerCornerDownLeft`  etc. should not be separate members but elements in an array or a list (indexed with symbolic constants). Their type should also contain the right hand side of the assignment, e.g. `wallInnerCornerDownLeft`. If these values are not classes (that can be null), provide an invalid/unspecified value. Then you can iterate through the sequence of hash types until tile is non-null or valid.